# UI component that appears like a cartoon-cloud when clicking an image

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface

I am working on a struts project. I have some UI requirements. 
I have a table - details info of items. In which 1 column can have 3 values. 
I want to make this column interactive such that by clicking data in this column in any rows, a windows or tray-like thing appear which should have some set of values to select.

I wonder if this could be done by Spinner or Select at a particular row.
But I want something more interactive.

If anyone has any suggestions on how this could be done : Maybe by Jquery, Ajax or JavaScript.

In short, I want some window/platform (something like thought-bubbles in cartoons) which should hold some elements which can call some actions. And this has to appear when a element is clicked.

Comment: Did you search online first? Try looking for "interactive jquery tooltip". Here's [one example](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-bubble.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of a [Pie Menu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_menu)?

Here are some javascript implementations/examples of a pie menu that you could use:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-pie-menu.html
http://wewillbeok.com/radial/
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-radial-menus-part-1
http://tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin#radmenu_tutorial_4